# An interesting proposition about linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm trying to prove the following:

Let $L:\mathbb{R}^s\to \mathbb{R}^s$ be a linear transformation such that, $\dim(\ker(L))>0$. If $b\in \ker(L^T)^{\perp}$, then there is $v\in \mathbb{R}^s$ such that $Lv=b$ and $v\perp \ker(L)$.

Is this always true?

My attempt:

I know that $\ker(L^{T})^{\perp}=Im(L)$. Therefore, there is $v\in \mathbb{R^s}$ such that $Lv=b$. How can I prove that $v\perp \ker(L)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose any such $v$, and let $P_\parallel(x)$ be the orthogonal projection of $x$ onto $\ker(L)$ and $P_\perp(x)$ the orthogonal projection onto $\ker(L)^\perp$.
Then $P_\perp(v) = v - P_\parallel(v)$, and
$$L(P_\perp(v)) = L(v - P_\parallel(v)) = L(v) - L(P_\parallel(v)) = L(v) = b$$
with $P_\perp(v) \perp \ker(L)$ by construction.

Comment: Thanks, nice approach!!